# Using JRuby+Sikuli on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, windows-7, jruby, sikuli

[This video](http://vimeo.com/fozzie63) shows JRuby+Sikuli working on Windows 7 or higher. There we have to `require "java"; require "sikuli"`.
So I've installed SikuliX using [sikuli-setup.jar](http://www.sikuli.org/download.html) and did some practice in Sikuli IDE.
However the `\jruby-1.7.15\bin\gem install java` gives `java requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.`, since [the latest JRuby installer](http://jruby.org/download) is `jruby 1.7.15 (1.9.3p392)`, so I had to `... install`**`-f`**`java`.
Then I had to manually set ENV variable `SIKULI_HOME`, but now I have this error:

```
irb> require "sikuli"
LoadError: Failed to load 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\nakilon\sikuli/sikuli-script.jar'
Is Sikuli installed?
```

And yes, I have no sikuli-script.jar in my SikuliX folder.
**So what is the proper way to make JRuby+Sikuli[X] to work on Windows 7/8?**

**UPD:**
I just realized, that `gem install sikuli` installs a 2 years old stuff, that isn't a Sikuli **X**.
So I did a hack -- renamed `sikuli-ide.jar` to `sikuli-script.jar`.
Trying to execute some lines from that video: `screen = Sikuli::Screen.new` goes fine.
But since `script = org.sikuli.script.SikuliScript.new` gives:

```
cannot load Java class org.sikuli.script.SikuliScript
```

I checked [github sources](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/tree/master/API/src/main/java/org/sikuli/script) -- there is really no SikuliScript class, so now I'm lost (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Current official JRuby gem way](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/tree/master/JRubyGem)
- [This question posted as GitHub issue, with solution](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/issues/61)
- [Google Drive shared folder with stack of files that seems to work for me](https://googledrive.com/host/0B3BLwu7Vb2U-VEVvVUwxLU9tYlU)

Checksums of files in it:

```
MD5 (jruby_windows_1_7_15.exe) = 61600abdb47177dc50c4ec887dc6c3f1
MD5 (sikulixsetup-1.1.0-Beta4.jar) = 7b836f4dad2e6817fd599f91cb1b9e7f
MD5 (sikulix-1.1.0.3.gem) = e1083cf09b55c917b62a34cc45cdded0
```

Google Drive doesn't allow to share `.exe`, so you'll see only two files.